# Need help with adding Classes to HTML Editor Elements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm using a WYSIWYG Editor called **CKEditor** and its really awesome. Inside the editor, whenever I add a new Heading/Text/DIV/Image/ anything else for that matter, I want it to stay attached with a class:

Like

```
<h2 class="blah">Sample Text</h2>

<img src="/abc.png" class="blah1" />
```

Here's a reference link:
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide

I'm not good with Javascript, if anyone can help me out, I would be really Grateful!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, the following code will ensure that  elements will have their "alt" attribute filled:

```
editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
{
    elements :
    {
        img : function( element )
        {
            if ( !element.attributes.alt )
                element.attributes.alt = 'An image';
        }
    }
});
```

Read the Overview (http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor) this example was taken from there.

You can do the same for "class".  Take a look at the existing output, then either add "class" if it's missing or replace them if that's your intent.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5024371/636615).

customize the dialogs during the define, add a "class" field and then set and get the contents in the setup and commit functions.

look at ckeditor/_samples/api_dialog.html for background on modifying dialogs.

for the Headings you'd have to look at modifying the commands.  Those don't have dialogs.

There's probably a way to always apply the same class based on the particular tag in the "data processor".  Do you want to always set the same class everytime or allow the user to choose the class, that's important because it changes your options quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot rQuinn, I need the same class to be applied everytime a user inserts a H1 or h2 or any tag for that matter, can't this be done without UI dialogs (Appending classes, without the user having the option to select the classes themselves through UI Dialogs)?

Comment: always adding the same class is (should be :) easier than modifying the dialogs.  checkout [jsdoc](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dataProcessor.html) and [overview](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor)

Comment: Could you show me some sample code so I can start off from there? Thank you very much for your time and patience. Imag xx