# CKEditor: Custom HTML when inserting image

Tags: html, image, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor as a rich text editor for my website. On that site I also have a custom image manager that I use in CKEditor using the "filebrowserImageBrowseUrl" config parameter.
This puts a "Browse Server" button in the image properties that lets me select a file from my image manager. This works just fine.

However, when I insert an image from my image manager and resize it in CKEditor this only adds a style attribute to the img tags. When people browse me website they will see the image as the size I want, but they also have to download a large amount of data, even if the image size is only a thumbnail.

My image manager has automatic resizing when you put a width and height as a query string to the image url.

How can I override the img tag CKEditor creates so that the selected width and height is put as query variables into the src attribute in the img tag in addition to the style attribute (so that CKEditor still knows which size the image has)?

I did find another question posted here: [CKEditor: Customized HTML on inserting an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024371/ckeditor-customized-html-on-inserting-an-image)
But the answers for that question doesn't seem to work since the width and height from that example contains the image's original size instead of the custom size. I've also debugged the various variables from those methods without finding the custom size.

So the question remains: How can I override CKEditor's output HTML to put an image's size as query variables as well as in the style attributes where CKEditor puts it by default?

**UPDATE**

To make all the comments below a bit more comprehensive, here's a condensed version:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    var editor = ev.editor,
        dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor,
        htmlFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.htmlFilter;

    htmlFilter.addRules( {
        elements : {
            $ : function( element ) {
                // Output dimensions of images as width and height attributes on src
                if ( element.name == 'img' ) {
                    var style = element.attributes.style;
                    if (style) {
                        // Get the width from the style.
                        var match = /(?:^|\s)width\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec( style ),
                            width = match && match[1];

                        // Get the height from the style.
                        match = /(?:^|\s)height\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec( style );
                        var height = match && match[1];

                        var imgsrc = element.attributes.src + "?width=" + width + "&height=" + height;

                        element.attributes.src = imgsrc;
                        element.attributes['data-cke-saved-src'] = imgsrc;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This code is run whenever the CKEditor generates the actual HTML, which happens when you either view the source by clicking the "Source" button, or by performing an HTTP POST of that page.

A small warning, though. The code above will keep appending the width and height query strings for each click on the "Source" button, or for each postback, so you might want to add some extra logic to filter out the width and height query strings before appending them to the src attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Output HTML sample](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/output_html.html) in your copy of CKEditor you can see how it uses the htmlFilter to change the images to put the dimensions in attributes. Based on that code you can write your own code so that it changes the url of the image.

And be careful: URLs are protected to avoid problems with the browsers, so modifying the "src" attribute might not be enough. Look at the properties of the object that you are modifying.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I tried tweaking the example to be run in config.js but it doesn't seem to run at all. I put alerts all over the place and the function for "elements" is never run.

So I now have the following in my config.js:

`CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
 var editor = ev.editor,
  dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor,
  htmlFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.htmlFilter;

 htmlFilter.addRules( {
  elements : {
   $ : function( element ) {
    alert("Never shows up");
   }
  }
 });
});`

Comment: (Sorry about the bad formatting. Still getting to grips with the stackoverflow syntax)

Comment: Is that code executed? You should put there a breakpoint or a console.log, anything to check that you have modified the correct file and that the browser has picked the changes. ( and I don't mean only that alert, but a several checks to verify that all that code is loaded and executed)

Comment: I did put more alerts in to pinpoint which code didn't run. The "instanceReady" function is executed, which should mean that everything but the function for the $ element is executed. There are no errors in the javascript console.

Comment: I've tested it and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/g2Pzb/ when I go to source mode it processes the contents and the alert shows up.

Comment: I see. The alert shows up whenever you click the "Source" button, but it is never fired when you insert an image, which is where I need it to fire.

Comment: Right, the htmlFilter is used when the content from the editor is converted to HTML, that's the best place to add your customizations so it will run no matter if the user resizes the image aftewards, if he pastes an image, drags&drop from somewhere else... You'll always have the control to verify that the images have the url that you want.

Comment: I'm starting to understand this. The elements function is only run, as you say, when the content is converted to HTML. This happens when you view the source, of course. When an image is inserted this only happens in the editor's viewstate and the HTML is not actually converted. The HTML _is_ converted when there is a postback, so the event is fired when I save the changes on my page.  However, as you rightly pointed out earlier, I can't change the src attribute of the element. Neither element.attributes.src nor element.src sets my new src path. Which should I use instead?

Comment: After a bit of trial and error (and object content debugging) I found this attribute that I also needed to set in addition to element.attributes.src: `element.attributes['data-cke-saved-src'] = "CustomSrcHere";`. Now I only have to process my generated src attribute to not duplicate my custom query strings on each save :)

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to understand everything and find the solution. Next time it will be a little easier :-)