# How to insert an img in CKEditor and always add a link to the full size image

Tags: ckeditor

I have CKEditor up and running but i would like that when an image is inserted, there is automatically an `<a href="...">` tag before it. This is so that people can click on the img to view its actual size.

At the moment, when inserting an image into the editor it appears like so:

```
<img alt="" src="/cms2/media/image/versuch(4).jpg" style="width: 1620px; height: 1080px;" />
```

I would like it to be in an `<a href="..."></a>` tag like so:

```
<a href="/cms2/media/image/versuch(4).jpg"><img alt="" src="/cms2/media/image/versuch(4).jpg" style="width: 1620px; height: 1080px;" /></a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried to do.

Comment: Please do not dump code into comments. Update your original post with the new information.

Comment: This is not uploading, this is inserting. Also, it helps if you read the question after asking it and see for yourself if it makes sense and is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the image dialog being closed and after it is closed, you need to insert the tag yourself. This is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071771/694325, I copied and edited the code from there:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'image') {
       dialogDefinition.onOk = function(e) {
          var imageSrcUrl = e.sender.originalElement.$.src;

          // HERE create your image element
          // Note that you will need to insert the width and height too!
          // Examine the available variables and DOM on how to do this.
          // I won't do it for you :)
          var htmlimg = '<img src="' + imageSrcUrl + '" style="width:100px;" />';
          var htmlstring = '<a href="' + imageSrcUrl + '">' + htmlimg + '</a>';

          CKEDITOR.instances.YOURINSTANCENAMEHERE.insertHtml(htmlstring);
       };
    }
}
```