# Auto adding a class to every img inserted to text - CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to have auto added class to every img I post in CKEditor

e.g.

`class="simple-class"` to every img I add

[image]

For now I only can do it manually by typing class manually in source, but it's problematic, especially when coming back from source mode this class I added is dissapearing.

Searched all possible topics about this and can't find right solution for this : /

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CKEditor: Customized HTML on inserting an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024371/ckeditor-customized-html-on-inserting-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
        // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
        var editor = ev.editor;
        if (dialogName == 'image') {
           dialogDefinition.onOk = function(e) {
              var imageSrcUrl = e.sender.originalElement.$.src;
              var imgHtml = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml("<img src=" + imageSrcUrl + " alt='' align='right'" + "class=className/>");
              editor.insertElement(imgHtml);
           };
        }
  }
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071771/4925026